# Странная ошибка при запуске Android приложения на Kotlin'е (возможно, FragmentManager)

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragment, android-resources, fragment-transaction

Я использую фрагменты для навигации. Приложение протестировано на моем устройстве (Honor 30i), телефоне Samsung A02 и эмуляторе Pixel 4, но после установки у пользователей возникает следующий странный краш в Crashlytics:

```
Fatal Exception: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException
Unable to find resource ID #0xffffffff
android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.getResourceTypeName (ResourcesImpl.java:310)
android.content.res.Resources.getResourceTypeName (Resources.java:2334)
androidx.fragment.app.FragmentAnim.loadAnimation (FragmentAnim.java:78)
androidx.fragment.app.DefaultSpecialEffectsController$AnimationInfo.getAnimation (DefaultSpecialEffectsController.java:801)
androidx.fragment.app.DefaultSpecialEffectsController.startAnimations (DefaultSpecialEffectsController.java:143)
androidx.fragment.app.DefaultSpecialEffectsController.executeOperations (DefaultSpecialEffectsController.java:119)
androidx.fragment.app.SpecialEffectsController.executePendingOperations (SpecialEffectsController.java:294)
androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.executeOpsTogether (FragmentManager.java:1798)
androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute (FragmentManager.java:1703)
androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.popBackStackImmediate (FragmentManager.java:771)
androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.popBackStackImmediate (FragmentManager.java:682)
androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.handleOnBackPressed (FragmentManager.java:620)
androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager$1.handleOnBackPressed (FragmentManager.java:407)
androidx.activity.OnBackPressedDispatcher.onBackPressed (OnBackPressedDispatcher.java:192)
androidx.activity.ComponentActivity.onBackPressed (ComponentActivity.java:552)
android.app.Activity.onKeyUp (Activity.java:3841)
android.view.KeyEvent.dispatch (KeyEvent.java:3648)
android.app.Activity.dispatchKeyEvent (Activity.java:4147)
androidx.core.app.ComponentActivity.superDispatchKeyEvent (ComponentActivity.java:122)
androidx.core.view.KeyEventDispatcher.dispatchKeyEvent (KeyEventDispatcher.java:84)
androidx.core.app.ComponentActivity.dispatchKeyEvent (ComponentActivity.java:140)
androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.dispatchKeyEvent (AppCompatActivity.java:599)
androidx.appcompat.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchKeyEvent (WindowCallbackWrapper.java:59)
androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl$AppCompatWindowCallback.dispatchKeyEvent (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:3090)
com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.dispatchKeyEvent (DecorView.java:758)
android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processKeyEvent (ViewRootImpl.java:7365)
android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess (ViewRootImpl.java:7191)
android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver (ViewRootImpl.java:6595)
android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext (ViewRootImpl.java:6652)
android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward (ViewRootImpl.java:6618)
android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward (ViewRootImpl.java:6786)
android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply (ViewRootImpl.java:6626)
android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply (ViewRootImpl.java:6843)
android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver (ViewRootImpl.java:6599)
android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext (ViewRootImpl.java:6652)
android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward (ViewRootImpl.java:6618)
android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply (ViewRootImpl.java:6626)
android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver (ViewRootImpl.java:6599)
android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext (ViewRootImpl.java:6652)
android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward (ViewRootImpl.java:6618)
android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward (ViewRootImpl.java:6819)
android.view.ViewRootImpl$ImeInputStage.onFinishedInputEvent (ViewRootImpl.java:7007)
android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager$PendingEvent.run (InputMethodManager.java:3624)
android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager.invokeFinishedInputEventCallback (InputMethodManager.java:3163)
android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager.finishedInputEvent (InputMethodManager.java:3154)
android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager$ImeInputEventSender.onInputEventFinished (InputMethodManager.java:3601)
android.view.InputEventSender.dispatchInputEventFinished (InputEventSender.java:143)
android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce (MessageQueue.java)
android.os.MessageQueue.next (MessageQueue.java:335)
android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:206)
android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:8633)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)
com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:602)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1130)
```

Я думал, что это из-за транзакций фрагментов с анимацией, поэтому сделал так:

```
fun navigate(fragment: Fragment, name: String?, animation: ScreenAnimation = ScreenAnimation.Sliding) {
        try {
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .setCustomAnimations(
                    animation.enter,
                    animation.exit,
                    animation.popEnter,
                    animation.popExit
                )
                .replace(R.id.nav_host, fragment)
                .addToBackStack(name)
                .commit()
        } catch (exc: Resources.NotFoundException) {
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.nav_host, fragment)
                .addToBackStack(name)
                .commit()
        }
    }
```

К сожалению не помогло, я много гуглил и несколько месяцев уже не могу решить эту проблему

Comment: Судя по [этому треду](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/13843) дело может быть в какой-то баге в какой-то библиотеке. Попробуйте обновить все вообще либы или наоборот их понизить. В любом случае - покажите какие библиотеки у вас подключены

Comment: маловероятно что проблема в библиотеках, я не добавлял новых, раньше не было такой ошибки, возможно я где-то упустил и просмотрел использование некорректного id ресурса